# C++ Boost program how to statically compiled with musl libc?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, glibc, musl

My program using C++ Boost and openSSL.

When I complied with "-static"，it notices that getaddrinfo() depends on the glibc version complied.And I found that this program work failed in some machine.

I notice that musl libc can resolve this problem.

Please tell me how to do to complie a c++ program which use Boost、Openssl with musl libc。